# Session data laravel App Service Provider save

Tags: php, laravel

App Service Provider boot  function in session save data not working.
Refresh page session lost :(

```
public function boot(Request $request){
    if (session('mydata') == ""){
        session(['mydata' => $request->input("variable")]);
    } else {
        session('mydata');
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use middleware instead of the AppServiceProvider in order to access the session.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```php
if ($request->session()->get('mydata') == "")
{
    $request->session()->put($request->input('variable'));
}
```

I don't think you should need the else - since the only time that will hit is when the session is already != "".

Comment: Refresh page session lost :(